# Carry forward data from previous row, based on conditions of various columns in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, mutate

## Dataset

I have a dataframe (`issue_termi_episode`) sampled like so:

```r
issue_termi_episode <- structure(
  list(
    new_conflictep_id = c(20504, 20505, 20506, 20507, 20508, 20902, 20903, 20904, 22003, 22101, 22102, 22103, 22104, 22105, 22202),
    conflict_id = c(205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 209, 209, 209, 220, 221, 221, 221, 221, 221, 222),
    location = c("Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Paraguay", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)"),
    incompatibility = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    conflict = c("Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Paraguay", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma)"),
    conflictepisode = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2),
    outcome = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5),
    version = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    intensity_level = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    region = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"),
    first_year_active = c(1990, 1993, 1996, 2016, 2018, 1989, 1997, 1999, 1989, 1989, 1994, 1997, 2000, 2013, 1990),
    last_year_active = c(1990, 1993, 1996, 2016, 2018, 1995, 1997, 2020, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2013, 1992),
    issue_territory = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_statestruc = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_gov = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
    issue_polrights = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_distrib = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -15L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

```r
issue_termi_episode
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 15 × 17
>    new_conflictep_id conflict_id location        incompatibility conflict   conflictepisode outcome version intensity_level region first_year_active last_year_active issue_territory issue_statestruc issue_gov issue_polrights issue_distrib
>                <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>
>  1             20504         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               4       5       3               1 2                   1990             1990               1                1         1               1             1
>  2             20505         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               5       5       3               1 2                   1993             1993               1                1         0               1             0
>  3             20506         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               6       5       3               1 2                   1996             1996               1                1         1               0             0
>  4             20507         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               7       5       3               1 2                   2016             2016               1                1         1               1             1
>  5             20508         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               8       5       3               1 2                   2018             2018               1                1         1               1             1
>  6             20902         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               2       2       3               2 3                   1989             1995               0                1         1               1             1
>  7             20903         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               3       2       3               1 3                   1997             1997               0                1         1               1             1
>  8             20904         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               4      NA       3               1 3                   1999             2020               0                1         1               1             1
>  9             22003         220 Paraguay                      2 Paraguay                 3       4       3               1 5                   1989             1989               0                1         1               1             0
> 10             22101         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               1       5       3               2 3                   1989             1992               1                1         1               1             1
> 11             22102         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               2       5       3               1 3                   1994             1995               1                1         0               1             1
> 12             22103         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               3       5       3               1 3                   1997             1998               1                1         1               1             1
> 13             22104         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               4       2       3               1 3                   2000             2011               1                1         1               1             1
> 14             22105         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               5       5       3               1 3                   2013             2013               1                1         0               1             0
> 15             22202         222 Myanmar (Burma)               2 Myanmar (…               2       5       3               1 3                   1990             1992               1                1         1               1             1
> ```

The last 5 variables (of the form `issue_*`) are binary (`0` or `1`).
The `new_conflictep_id` is unique to every row, and `conflict_id` is a grouping variable, often same for several rows but also sometimes just for one row.

## Goal

Grouped by `conflict_id`, I want to "carry forward" the data (`1`s and `0`s) of all the `issue_*` variables to the next row, but only if

1. the gap between `first_year_active` of that next row and `last_year_active` of the previous row is 5 years or less; **and**
2. all `issue_*` variables of that next row are equal to `0`.

My desired output would update row 5 of the sample, where `new_conflictep_id` = `20508`...

```
  new_conflictep_id conflict_id ... first_year_active last_year_active issue_territory issue_statestruc issue_gov issue_polrights issue_distrib
1             20504         205 ...              1990             1990               1                1         1               1             1
2             20505         205 ...              1993             1993               1                1         0               1             0
3             20506         205 ...              1996             1996               1                1         1               0             0
4             20507         205 ...              2016             2016               1                1         1               1             1
#                           ^^^                                   ^^^^                                                                         
5             20508         205 ...              2018             2018               0                0         0               0             0
#                           ^^^                  ^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6             20902         209 ...              1989             1995               0                1         1               1             1
```

...by filling the `issue_*` variables with all `1`s, from the row above.

```
  new_conflictep_id conflict_id ... first_year_active last_year_active issue_territory issue_statestruc issue_gov issue_polrights issue_distrib
1             20504         205 ...              1990             1990               1                1         1               1             1
2             20505         205 ...              1993             1993               1                1         0               1             0
3             20506         205 ...              1996             1996               1                1         1               0             0
4             20507         205 ...              2016             2016               1                1         1               1             1
#                                                                                    ↓                ↓         ↓               ↓             ↓
5             20508         205 ...              2018             2018               1                1         1               1             1
#                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6             20902         209 ...              1989             1995               0                1         1               1             1
```

## Attempts

I tried different solutions with **`dplyr`**. First:

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
issue_termi_episode <- issue_termi_episode %>%
arrange(conflict_id, first_year_active) %>%
group_by(conflict_id) %>%
mutate(across(starts_with("issue_"), ~ ifelse(first_year_active - lag(last_year_active, default = first_year_active[1] + 10) <= 5 & all(. == 0), lag(.), .)))
```

From the content of my data, it results that for the first row within a group of `conflict_id`, it is not necessary to make any changes (which would be not possible anyway, because there is no data to carry forward from above). Therefore I added `+ 10` to the default-argument in `lag()`, so the condition never applies for the first row.
This code just created `NA`s in some random places, but neither in those rows that I wanted to target with my conditions, nor did it fill these `NA`s in all of the 5 `issue_*` variables of a given row (as I wanted).

I then tried a work around, creating first a new variable that fills in a certain value (`333`) if my conditions are met (to later use that variable to carry the data forward):

```
issue_termi_episode <- issue_termi_episode %>%
  arrange(conflict_id, first_year_active) %>%
  group_by(conflict_id) %>%
  mutate(row_fill = ifelse(first_year_active - lag(last_year_active, default = first_year_active[1] + 10) <= 5 &all(c_across(starts_with("issue_")) == 0), 
                                 333, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("issue_"), ~ ifelse(row_fill == 333, lag(.), .)))
```

However, in the newly created `row_fill`, only `0` is filled in. That leads me to the conclusion that my condition is not recognized. Trying the condition of all `issue_*` variables `= 0, 333` is filled in very few but not all rows that should meet my condition. I can't get behind, why. The other condition (tested the same way) is working fine.

```
issue_termi_episode <- issue_termi_episode %>%
  arrange(conflict_id, first_year_active) %>%
  group_by(conflict_id) %>%
  mutate(row_fill = if_else(all(c_across(starts_with("issue_")) == 0), 
                                 333, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I would greatly appreciate some help, be it a complete solution in another approach, or just debugging my condition.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @cornel Please update your question with the console output from running `head(issue_termi_episode, n = 15) %>% dput()`.  This generates a sample of (the first 15 rows from) your dataset.

Comment: @cornel I'm not sure why your question was closed: I understood your gist as soon as you posted it...though you could have formatted your prose to be more readable.  Anyway, here is a solution in [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78003058#comment137518349_78003058):

Comment: @cornel  Start with `library(dplyr)` and `library(tidyr)` for the sake of [`tidyr::fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html). Then generate `issue_termi_episode` and perform this workflow: `issue_termi_episode %>% group_by(conflict_id) %>% mutate(is_blank = if_all(starts_with("issue"), ~ . == 0), is_close = abs(first_year_active - lag(last_year_active, 1)) <= 5, needs_fill = if_else(is.na(is_close), FALSE, is_blank & is_close), across(starts_with("issue"), ~ if_else(needs_fill, NA, .))) %>% fill(starts_with("issue")) %>% ungroup() %>% select(!c(is_blank, is_close, needs_fill))`

Comment: @Greg thanks for you reply, but I receive an error: Problem with `mutate()` input ..4. ℹ ..4 = `across(starts_with("issue"), ~if_else(needs_fill, NA, .)).` x false must be a double vector, not a logical vector. I tried putting `across(starts_with("issue"), ~ if_else(needs_fill, NA, as.logical(.)))`, but then all issues variables are only filled with TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @cornel  If every variable in `starts_with("issue")` is indeed a numeric vector — with exclusively `1`s and `0`s, as in your sample of `issue_termi_episode` — then my original code should work.  Now [`if_else()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) requires the `yes` and the `no` to have the same type, so you might need to coerce them both to numeric with `~if_else(needs_fill, as.numeric(NA), as.numeric(.))`.  **Tell me: are you _certain_ that _all_ the `starts_with("issue")` variables are really numbers (`is.numeric()`)?**

Comment: @Greg yes `> is.numeric(issue_termi_episode$issue_distrib)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(issue_termi_episode$issue_territory)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(issue_termi_episode$issue_statestruc)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(issue_termi_episode$issue_gov)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(issue_termi_episode$issue_polrights)
[1] TRUE`; However, your code coercing both `yes` and `no` to numeric in `if_else` did work for me! Now it's running as I wanted to, thanks a lot!

Comment: @cornel  Awesome, I'm glad to hear it!  I'm curious: does it work with simply `if_else(needs_fill, NA_integer_, .)`?

Comment: @Greg Nope, it does not, slightly different error code though: `x `false` must be an integer vector, not a double vector.`Thanks again!

Comment: @cornel  Last experiment: try it with `if_else(needs_fill, NA_real_, .)`.

Comment: @cornel  Thanks for confirming.  It all boils down to ensuring the `NA`s have the same (`numeric`) type as the `issue_*` columns targeted by `.` in the `~if_else()`.

Comment: @cornel  I have posted the solution as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049334).  Kindly upvote and accept it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Here is the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org) solution, which I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137518349) and you [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/137562856) in the comments.  It converts the relevant `0`s into `NA`s, and [`fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html)s them from the data above.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  # For filling.


# ...
# Code to generate 'issue_termi_episode'.
# ...


# Set the "closeness" threshold.
year_threshold <- 5


issue_termi_episode %>%
    
    # Sort groups in chronological order.
    arrange(conflict_id, first_year_active) %>%
    
    # Prepare for filling within groups.
    group_by(conflict_id) %>%
    mutate(
        # Flag rows with only 0s.
        all_zero = if_all(starts_with("issue_"), ~ . == 0),
        
        # Flag rows whose year is "close" to the prior.
        is_close = abs(first_year_active - lag(last_year_active)) <= year_threshold,
        
        # Flag rows that are both, and should thus be overwritten.
        needs_fill = if_else(is.na(is_close), FALSE, all_zero & is_close),
        
        # Replace their 0s with NAs.
        across(starts_with("issue_"), ~ if_else(needs_fill, NA_real_, .))
    ) %>%
    
    # Fill downwards with the prior values.
    fill(starts_with("issue_")) %>%
    
    # Clean up from preparations.
    ungroup() %>%
    select(!c(all_zero, is_close, needs_fill))
```

## Result

Given an `issue_termi_episode` dataset like your sample...

```r
issue_termi_episode <- structure(
  list(
    new_conflictep_id = c(20504, 20505, 20506, 20507, 20508, 20902, 20903, 20904, 22003, 22101, 22102, 22103, 22104, 22105, 22202),
    conflict_id = c(205, 205, 205, 205, 205, 209, 209, 209, 220, 221, 221, 221, 221, 221, 222),
    location = c("Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Iran", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Paraguay", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)", "Myanmar (Burma)"),
    incompatibility = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
    conflict = c("Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Iran: Kurdistan", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Paraguay", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma): Karen", "Myanmar (Burma)"),
    conflictepisode = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2),
    outcome = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5),
    version = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    intensity_level = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    region = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"),
    first_year_active = c(1990, 1993, 1996, 2016, 2018, 1989, 1997, 1999, 1989, 1989, 1994, 1997, 2000, 2013, 1990),
    last_year_active = c(1990, 1993, 1996, 2016, 2018, 1995, 1997, 2020, 1989, 1992, 1995, 1998, 2011, 2013, 1992),
    issue_territory = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_statestruc = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_gov = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
    issue_polrights = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    issue_distrib = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -15L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

...this should yield your desired result.

> ```
> # A tibble: 15 × 17
>    new_conflictep_id conflict_id location        incompatibility conflict   conflictepisode outcome version intensity_level region first_year_active last_year_active issue_territory issue_statestruc issue_gov issue_polrights issue_distrib
>                <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>
>  1             20504         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               4       5       3               1 2                   1990             1990               1                1         1               1             1
>  2             20505         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               5       5       3               1 2                   1993             1993               1                1         0               1             0
>  3             20506         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               6       5       3               1 2                   1996             1996               1                1         1               0             0
>  4             20507         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               7       5       3               1 2                   2016             2016               1                1         1               1             1
>  5             20508         205 Iran                          1 Iran: Kur…               8       5       3               1 2                   2018             2018               1                1         1               1             1
>  6             20902         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               2       2       3               2 3                   1989             1995               0                1         1               1             1
>  7             20903         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               3       2       3               1 3                   1997             1997               0                1         1               1             1
>  8             20904         209 Philippines                   2 Philippin…               4      NA       3               1 3                   1999             2020               0                1         1               1             1
>  9             22003         220 Paraguay                      2 Paraguay                 3       4       3               1 5                   1989             1989               0                1         1               1             0
> 10             22101         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               1       5       3               2 3                   1989             1992               1                1         1               1             1
> 11             22102         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               2       5       3               1 3                   1994             1995               1                1         0               1             1
> 12             22103         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               3       5       3               1 3                   1997             1998               1                1         1               1             1
> 13             22104         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               4       2       3               1 3                   2000             2011               1                1         1               1             1
> 14             22105         221 Myanmar (Burma)               1 Myanmar (…               5       5       3               1 3                   2013             2013               1                1         0               1             0
> 15             22202         222 Myanmar (Burma)               2 Myanmar (…               2       5       3               1 3                   1990             1992               1                1         1               1             1
> ```

Notice how the `5`th row has been filled from the `4`th, across all `issue_*` columns:

```r
  # ... %>%
  slice(4:5) %>%
  select(ends_with("_id"), starts_with("issue_"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 × 7
>   new_conflictep_id conflict_id issue_territory issue_statestruc issue_gov issue_polrights issue_distrib
>               <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>
> 1             20507         205               1                1         1               1             1
> 2             20508         205               1                1         1               1             1
> ```

## Note

If a row of `0`s is the topmost in its group, it is left untouched.  This is conceptually desirable, because there is no "prior" data we can use to fill it.

Such behavior is facilitated by [`lag()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html), which [*"pads...a missing value"*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html#arguments) at the top: namely [`NA`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NA.html).  This yields an `NA` for `is_close`...

```r
        # ...
        
        # Flag rows whose year is "close" to the prior.
        is_close = abs(first_year_active - lag(last_year_active)) <= year_threshold,
        #                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        # ...
```

...and thus a `FALSE` for `needs_fill`:

```r
        # ...
        
        # Flag rows that are both, and should thus be overwritten.
        needs_fill = if_else(is.na(is_close), FALSE, all_zero & is_close)
        #                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        # ...
```